# Get playlists from iPod library - Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm build an app which should import all the iPod library items. I have done with importing all the songs, now i want to know how to import the playlists and albums from the library. Provide me some suggestions or the example Code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope its enough to give all information to you, Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html).

And if you are looking for sample code then visit [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/).

It will return all albums,

```
MPMediaQuery *allAlbums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray *albumArray = [allAlbums collections];
```